# Building libtorrent with openssl with BJam

Tags: c++, bjam, libtorrent, msvc12

I am trying to build libtorrent (http://www.libtorrent.org/) using the provided jamfile. If I try to build it in its vanilla state everything goes well. I am then building using this command:

```
bjam msvc-12.0 boost=source
```

However I want to build it with OpenSSL which there seem to be support for. This is where I run into problems. Most likely because it is the first time I use Bjam (actually anything else than make files). I now try to run the following command:

```
bjam msvc-12.0 boost=source encryption=openssl
```

Now the compiler starts to complain about not finding the OpenSSL include files. 
So I guess I have to include this path in the JAM file. But I have no idea where.
I also tried to add the path into the INCLUDE environment varaible in windows but that doesn't seem to be picked up by BJAM or msvc. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of how this is normally done on windows is by installing libraries and headers into visual studio's `include` and `lib` folders.
(That's how I install openssl on windows at least).

The jamfile is also supposed to pick up `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` environment variables, which you could use to introduce the library- and include paths. However, it only does this when `boost=system` is specified, i.e. you're building against "system" boost libraries instead of from source.

Comment: Thx. This seems to be the case. Because I tried adding it to LDFLAGS and CXXFLAGS as I would have with make but it never seemed to pick it up.  In the end I just moved all include files to libtorrents include folder which feels a lot like cheating.

Comment: The libs on the other hand I managed to add to the jam file by adding: <search>%MYLIBPATH% on the same line as where the name of the lib is stated.